# Adding text to a bitmap with canvas

Tags: c#, android, canvas, text, bitmap

I have some code that adds text to a bitmap. This works well unless the text is wider than the original image.

How do I go about making the image wide enough for my text to display correctly?

Here is my code:

```
private BitmapDescriptor GetCustomBitmapDescriptor(string text)
{
    Bitmap baseBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon);
    Bitmap bitmap = baseBitmap.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
    Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();

    paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);

    float bitmapMiddle = bitmap.Width / 2.0f;

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    canvas.DrawText(text, bitmapMiddle - (bounds.Right / 2.0f), bitmap.Height, paint);

    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBitmap(bitmap);

    return (icon);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just color code and it is working

private Bitmap GetCustomBitmapDescriptor(String text)
    { 
        Bitmap baseBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launche);
        Bitmap bitmap = baseBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();

```
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    float bitmapMiddle = bitmap.getWidth() / 2.0f;

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawText(text, bitmapMiddle - (bounds.right  / 2.0f), bitmap.getHeight(), paint);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, and the text still does not fully show if the text is a long string. For example, try this string as the text: "Test text, test text : Test text, test text".

Comment: You can use font size to fit all the text.